# Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++

Is it possibe to add together two `char const*` parameters? 
Code should look something like this one. I need `c` to be `char const` like `a` and `b`. If someone know how to make this, please help me :)
Thanks in advance

```
char const *a = "something";
char const *b = " more";
char const *c = a + b;
```

Comment: No that is not possible.  Why not use `std::string`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `std::string` if you want your strings to work like objects from other languages.

```
std::string a = "something";
std::string b = " more";
std::string c = a + b;
```

If you need to pass the resultant string to something that expects a `const char *`, you can call the `c_str()` function on the string.

Comment: I can't. system("") needs to be char const*, I forgot to add that part.

Comment: Read the last sentence again.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `char` array to create result of concatenation:

```
char* result; 
result = static_cast<char*>( calloc ( strlen( a) + strlen( b) + 1, 
                                                             sizeof( char)));
strcpy( result, a); // copy string a into the result
strcat( result, b); // append b to the result
```

However in C++ you should use `std::string`:

```
std::string a = "something";
std::string b = " more";

std::string result = a + b;
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. And even when using such C techniques, you can do without C-style casts in C++. Use `std::reinterpret_cast` or `std::static_cast` where appropriate. As you said, the best thing is to forget all of this stuff and just use `std::string`.